# How to implement HMVC using Kohana's cascading file system

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, hmvc

Kohana 3.2 was designed to support the HMVC design pattern. The HMVC pattern consists of nested MVC-triads. Yet as far as I can tell, Kohana's cascading file system requires all Models and Controllers to be placed within a top 'classes' directory, and Views into a top 'views' directory. If Model/Controllers are thus separated from Views at the top level of the file system, then how are we supposed to implement nested MVC-triads?

[image]

Comment: The diagrams only indicate logical inheritance, and only among controllers.  How does physical separation impact this?  What have you tried?

Comment: My assumption/hope is that one can implement a physical manifestation of the HMVC pattern in the file system to mirror the logical one. Otherwise controllers will be pointing all over the place and the modularity benefits of HMVC would be lost.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you'd want to hack the way that views are processed, but you can extend the `Kohana_View` class so that `set_filename()` function will accept any directory that you want.

If you want an auto-loading feature similar to controllers / models, you could implement it yourself.

For example (untested):

```
public function set_filename($view)
{        
    // Transform the class name into a path
    $file = str_replace('_', '/', strtolower($view));

    if ($path = Kohana::find_file('classes', $file))
    {
        // Store the file path locally
        $this->_file = $path;

        return $this;
    }  

    throw new View_Exception('The requested view :view could not be found', array(
        ':view' => $view,
    ));
}
```

Comment: @Nathan- thanks. I just didn't think I'd need to hack the cascading file system because it was supposedly built around HMVC to begin with... But looks like you're probably right that this is the only way to do it- kinda weird.

Comment: Please do not put templates for the View class in a folder dedicated for class files. I think that I now understand what you want, an edit coming up.

Comment: I thought Yarin wanted a way to store view templates with controllers / models for organization and still maintain default Kohana functionality (i.e. using `View::factory($filename)`). Of course it would be better to implement a structure that would add view classes alongside controllers / models and leave the templates elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> Yet as far as I can tell, Kohana's cascading file system requires all Models and Controllers to be placed within a top 'classes' directory, and Views into a top 'views' directory.

What you seem to want is a folder structure like Kohana 2, codeigniter and most likely other frameworks, which have dedicated folders for controllers, models, and views. Kohana 3 has a dedicated folder for classes. The way Kohana 3 is built enforces that controllers should have a Controller_ prefix. The Kohana 3 autoloader will look for classes with a Controller_ prefix in the classes/controller folder.

Then Kohana 3 also comes with very basic Model and View classes. The Kohana 3 core does not use the Model class as far as I am aware and it uses the View class only on a few occasions. But the convention to give models the Model_ prefix can be found in Model::factory(), it is not enforced however. You do not have to use them.

The View class looks for templates in de views folder. The (not recommended by Zombor) [View_Module](https://github.com/zombor/View-Model) by Zombor (one of the devs) also happends to look there. The (redommended by Zombor) [KOstache](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache) module, again by Zombor, looks for its templates in the templates folder. Both modules let you create View-Model classes for which the convention is to have the View_ prefix so they end up in classes/view. But nothing stops you from creating a View_ class which extends View for every template you put into the views folder and hardcode the path for that View-Model.

Please respect that the classes folder is only for classes.

Comment: @Darsstar- What I think you're saying is: While the Kohana 2 filesystem allowed nested MVC triads within the file system, Kohana 3's enforced seperation of Model-Controller classes from Views precludes it?

Comment: If you choose to only use the View class as your View-Model you choose to move logic to your templates. If you would create View-Models for each template and put the logic in those View-Models. Then the templates only have control over what should go where. Since View-Models are classes they should go into the classes folder. And since you clearly want them all in the same subfolder you should give them the View_ prefix. Then you get the seperation you want. So YOU are plecluding it, not Kohana. Kohana just comes with a bad View-Model out of the box.